# Issue posting Video URL through UIactivityViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to post a video to Facebook, vimeo, whatever through UIActivityViewController. I'm using iOS7. I've heard that its possible in iOS7 but for some reason I'm having trouble getting it to work.

My code is:

```
NSString *shareString = @"My Personal Flick";
    NSURL *url = _URL;
    AVURLAsset *anAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];

NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareString, anAsset, nil];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can someone please explain to me where I'm going wrong?

Just to understand I have a button that opens UIImagePickerViewController where I can choose a video and than it saves the video as _URL - that's were I'm getting the _URL from.

```
------CODE FOR CREATING _URL OF VIDEO FILE-----------
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Chose Image.");
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    _imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{


NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
    == kCFCompareEqualTo)
{

    NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

    NSURL *_URL=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

     NSLog(@"%@",moviePath);

    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: are you shure you need the assets? I'm sending pdf files but i put just the fileurl to the activity items, no asset:

Comment: I don't know maybe i don't need the Asset but I'm not sending PDF i want to send Video. Do you know how i could do this?? Asset isn't working so i guess your probably right that i don't need it.

Comment: i would try adding the url directly to the activityItems, its an attachment, like many other filetypes, and for an attachment you only need to add the fileURL.

Comment: So just NSURL *url =_URL?? if so than its possible that I'm not storing the _URL correctly. If you don't mind could you possibly look at my code for creating the _URL and see if anything is wrong? Ill post it in my question - i would appreciate it.

Comment: I changed my code based on your edit but when I try to post using UIactivityViewController no Video is attached. Any idea? Thank you for your help so far. This has been bugging me for a while

Comment: Could you show me in an edit how to do that? Sorry Or just explain where to put the self.fileURL in my code. Is that under the UIactivityViewController button or under Imagepicker?

Comment: try to find out, you should know now what is nescasarry, see my last comment :-)

Comment: Wherever i add the self.fileURL = (NSURL*).. it gives me and error saying incompatible pointer types assigning to NSString from NSURL. Im sorry I know I'm not being helpful but its just not working for me,

Comment: sorry: try this: define as a property in your .h file:`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *fileURL`. then you would do `self.fileURL = (NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];` and then later `NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareString, self.fileURL, nil];`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!. Is there anyway to give you credit?? Id give you the Check for the answer but you only commented

Comment: i will add an answer then you can except :-)

Comment: AWESOME! you deserve it!

Comment: Could I ask one more question - its fine if you don't want to answer ill just delete this comment after . Is it possible to get a Thumbnail image of the video after selecting it??

Comment: i dont know exactly. you could try to see if `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`is returning an image. you would call something like this: `UIImage *previewImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]`

Comment: Thank you again. I hope the Check helps!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to an asset. the movie is like any other filetype an attachment and for that you need only the url. do the following:

in your .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *fileURL;
```

in your .m file:
instead of

```
NSURL *_URL=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```

use

```
self.fileURL = (NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```

and instead of

```
NSURL *url = _URL;
AVURLAsset *anAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareString, anAsset, nil];
```

simply use:

```
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareString, self.fileURL, nil];
```